# Remove a function from click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmpp

Im very very new to JS and JQuery so please bear with me.

I have a dropdown list - and if you click the  list, it will call a function, which will open a floating box (div). Now we want that box to display upon log-in, disconnecting its relationship to click event. But if I just take the codes out of the function, place it in the script - like the other divs, either my page renders incorrectly or nothing displays.

here is what is in my HTML:

```
<li><input class="option_btn room_search" value="Search for Room"/></li>
```

and here is how my script looks like:

```
$("input.room_search").click(function() {
    //var roomSearch = new jabberwerx.ui.MUCSearchView(muc, demo_config.conferencealias); 

    var roomSearch = new jabberwerx.ui.MUCSearchView(muc, conferencealias); 

    roomSearch.event("actionComplete").bind(function(evt) {
        try {
            try this...

        } catch (e) {
            alert("An exception occurred while trying to create/join the MUC room.\n Details: " +
                  e.message);
        }
        roomSearch.destroy();
    });
    roomSearch.render().appendTo(".muc_search");
    roomSearch.dimensions({width:600, height:400});                   
});
```

Please help me, I have tried to find a forum with his concern but I dont think I have the correct keywords. Thank you!

Comment: When you removed the code from the click handler did you put it in a `$(document).ready(function() { /*your code here*/ });` handler instead? Your code tries to append to the `".muc_search"` element, so you need to run it after that element has been parsed.

Comment: Yes, it is inside that handler - although the original code with the click event is also inside the handler. 

You are right on the "Your code tries to append to the ".muc_search" element". I changed ".muc_search" to "div.muc_search" and my page rendered correctly - still not showing the floating box by default though.

Meanwhile, I found that I can force the click event upon log in so for now, I can use this work around: 
$("input.room_search").trigger('click');

Answer (score 0):

I dont get your question completely, but looking at the question, the click event can be easily unbind by

```
$('#mySelectr').unbind('click');
```

Inside the unbind functon, give name of any event you want to unbind.